# Layman question about relativistic acceleration

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, acceleration, speed-of-light

Alan is a hypothetical observer in a hypothetical spaceship accelerating at 1g. Alan would feel 1g of gravity because of his acceleration, and his speed will increase by apx 9.8m per second.
What happens when he approaches close to $c$ and experiences relativistic effects? His speed cannot continue increasing at the same rate indefinitely, right? Instead, his acceleration would increase his mass. So if his speed won't increase at the same rate, would he still feel the 1g because of his acceleration?

Comment: When he approaches $c$ relative to what? Right now, you are moving with a speed of $0.99c$ in some inertial reference frame; how does it feel, and what do you notice?

Comment: An excellent comment, @Sandejo. I wonder if it is something about the way in which relativity is taught that causes people to overlook the point and think themselves into all kinds of misconceptions as a consequence.

Answer (score 0):

Alan always measures his own acceleration as $1g$, whether he uses an accelerometer or measures the rate of change of velocity of a distant non-accelerating object whose initial velocity relative to Alan is low. He measures his own mass to be constant.

Assuming he is accelerating in a straight line, he measures the rest of the universe getting smaller along the axis of his acceleration. In the direction of his acceleration, the universe appears to be evolving at a faster speed, including the emission of light, resulting in the color of light from in front of him being shifted towards higher (bluer) frequencies and becoming brighter. The opposite is the case behind him, which will appear to be redder, slower, and dimmer. When he measures the velocity of an object in front of him to approach $+c$, its distance to him approaches zero, and when he measures the velocity of an object behind him to approach $-c$, it emits no light.

An inertial observer watching Alan sees Alan's clock (and other processes, like his thoughts and movements) slow, such that while they disagree on the distances and times involved, they agree on how long it takes in Alan's frame for events to occur.

For example, Alan sees a star about one light-second ahead of him, approaching at slightly less than the speed of light, so it will reach him in one second.

Beth, an inertial observer, sees the star about one light-year ahead of Alan, who is approaching the star at slightly less than the speed of light; he will reach it in about one year in Beth's frame. But Beth measures Alan's clock ticking once per year, so they agree that Alan will pass the star in one second in Alan's frame.

Alan, observing Beth, sees Beth receding backwards at the same speed as the star. He sees that her clock ticks just once per year. However, he knows that light from the star passing him one second from now will take a long time to reach her because she is moving away from the source of the light. He does the simple algebra calculation and concludes that it will be one year in Beth's time before Beth sees the star pass Alan.

So everyone agrees about what happens when for whom, they just disagree about the geometry of spacetime along the axis of Alan's acceleration.

---

Alan never measures any relative velocities higher than c.

Suppose Alan starts on Earth with you and me and travels at about 1g for 1 year towards Andromeda, $2.5$ million light years away.

I'll have him turn off his rocket thruster to take measurements as I don't want to have to check whether he has put us behind an accelerated-frame event horizon. You can ignore this paragraph.

Let's make his acceleration whatever it would need to be to get to 0.87c in 1 year - it'll be close to 1g and makes the math easier. 0.87c corresponds to a time dilation factor of 2.0 - that is: every time an observer on Earth measures Alan's clock tick once, that observer's clock ticks twice, and vice  versa.

Now, according to Alan, Alan is stationary in a trivial sense. After all, no matter how long Alan waits between measurements, Alan is always *right there*: displacement $\Delta s = 0 \implies \Delta s/ \Delta t = 0$. It is the rest of the universe that is moving backwards.

Alan has many ways of telling that he has gotten faster. First, his accelerometer read $1g$ the whole way. Any time he looked at his rocket exhaust, he saw it accelerating away from him at $1g$. Also, he can measure the rest of the universe zipping backwards.

Most significantly, in Alan's frame, Andromeda is zipping towards Alan, but it's not $2.5MLY$ away. We know that Alan will get there at his current velocity (0.87c) in around 3 million years, and in that time Alan will have measured 1.5 million years to pass - so Alan measures Andromeda to be less than $1.5 MLY$ away.

Alan can repeat this process any number of times, each time reducing the distance (in his frame) between him and Andromeda. Not by crossing most of the distance - as a fraction of the distance he measures between his starting point and Andromeda, he's barely crossed any of it at all - but by boosting into a frame with different spacetime geometry in which the total distance, start to finish, is much smaller.

In our frame, we see him asymptotically approaching the speed of light and having a time dilation factor that explains why he measures the distance to be length-contracted.

In his frame, he sees us asymptotically approaching the speed of light in the opposite direction across the length-contracted universe.

Comment: A very nice answer, gs.

Comment: Gs thanks for the detailed answer. So if Alan measures his rate of change in speed at 1g constantly relative to that distant non accelerating object, then at some point he would measure his speed to be C, and then more than C ?

Comment: @Alen Mostly no but a tiny bit bit "yes, in a manner of speaking". I will expand my answer as the reply is too long for a comment.

Comment: @Alen also note that the object has to have a low ('nonrelativistic') relative velocity to Alan for him to measure its acceleration as $g$.

Comment: gs thank you for the detailed answer and being patient with my seemingly stupid questions.
So if I understand this correctly, According to Alan, because his time clicks twice as slow at .87c, and there's some space contraction, anytime his speed is increased, the distance and time changes cause his speed increase to sort of 'cancel'? I'm trying to understand how is it possible for Alan to measure his speed (Or the speed of Andromeda) increase indefinitely but not pass C. Again, thank you for your patience and time.

Comment: @Alen That's almost right. The distance and time changes to make *the speed of light* stay the same. The closer "the speed Andromeda and the Milky Way relative to Adam" is to "the speed of light", the more "the distance between Andromeda and the Milky Way measured by Alan" and "the time measured by Alan" change to make "the speed of Andromeda and the Milky Way" stay the same. However, if Alan drops a rock out of his window once per year (as measured by Alan), after a year, his velocity relative to the most recently dropped rock is $-0.87c$

Comment: while the more distant, older rocks asymptotically approach $-c$.

Answer (score 0):

An accelerated frame can measure its acceleration by checking how the relative velocity of another (inertial) frame is increasing with the time. When we say that our car can accelerate $0$ to $100 km/h$ in $10s$, it is about this concept of acceleration. The inertial frame of reference for the car is the road.

But there is another way to measure it: we can let some object in the air inside the car and check its horizontal acceleration with respect to the car. The object is accelerated in the car's frame without any applied force, what lead us to the concept of fictitious force for non inertial frames.

Both methods give the same result for low relative velocities, at least within the experimental margin of error. But for relativistic speeds, the difference can be meaningful.

The second way of measurement is called proper acceleration and is normally what is called acceleration in relativistic examples. When the average relative velocity of the celestial bodies is close to c for the ship, it will measure almost no acceleration in the first meaning of the word. But it can keep its proper acceleration $g$ while there is fuel to burn.